# Memory issues with CreateProcess

Tags: c++, windows, service, createprocess

I have written a Windows Service program in C++. One of the tasks it performs is to run a very large business app written in PowerBuilder. It performs a bunch of database processes and transfers data back and forth with SharePoint. The PowerBuilder app gets to a certain point where it aborts and the likely cause is because services have a limited 'desktop heap' compared to normal desktop apps.
As a test we tried using a generic service app called AlwaysUp to run the PowerBuilder app and somehow it has no problems at all. I am stumped as to why AlwaysUp has no issues. Here is the code I use to launch the PowerBuilder app:

```
   // report running status
   ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING;
   SetServiceStatus(hStatus, &ServiceStatus);

   // run the application
   event = CreateEvent(0, FALSE, FALSE, 0);
   if ( CreateProcess( NULL, CommandLine, NULL, NULL, FALSE,
            DETACHED_PROCESS | dwPriority, NULL,
            szModule, &si, &pi ) == 0 ) {
      // CreateProcess Failed
      return 0;
   }

   // wait for either the process to end or stop event
   WaitHandles[0] = pi.hProcess;
   WaitHandles[1] = event;
   do {
      dwError = WaitForMultipleObjects(2, WaitHandles, FALSE, 60000);
      switch ( dwError ) {
         case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
            // process ended
            bRunning = FALSE;
            break;
         case WAIT_OBJECT_0+1:
            // event triggered
            bRunning = FALSE;
            break;
         case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
            // timeout
            break;
         default:
            // error
            bRunning = FALSE;
            break;
      }
   } while ( bRunning );

   // close the handles
   CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
   CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
   CloseHandle(event);
```

Comment: You're guessing at what the problem is ("the likely cause").  Don't guess.  Find out, using a debugger, event log, or something.

Comment: PowerBuilder is similar to VB6 and creates windowed apps, not console. The app written in PowerBuilder works perfectly fine when run by the user or by AlwaysUp as a service. I can't debug to get the exact cause because I didn't write it, I am only doing the service part of the project.

Comment: Calling `CreateProcess()` in a service will run the app in the same session as the service. Services run in a non-interactive session, so it is really not a good idea to run GUI apps in that session. Have you tried `CreateProcessAsUser()` to run the app in an interactive session instead?

Comment: Have you confirmed that AlwaysUp runs the application in the services session (0) using a non-iterative WindowStation (i.e. not WinSta0) that's created for the logon session? If so, then the issue is not the smaller UI object heap that's used for desktops in non-interactive window stations.